# Send html code from UI to node and adding it to a pug template

Tags: html, node.js, reactjs, pug, react-quill

Hello so as the title says, I need to be able to fill a textbox with html code and send it to to my node backend and then out it into my pug template to show the html code writes in te textbox ( now I'm using react-quill but this always wraps the thing that I write between

tags ) all the sending process is ok but I've been unable to found a way of doing this, dunno if a text area couldwork,with reacquill just work with the normal tools on the editor, but not like sending a current code with all syntax of html, like with doctype tag or the html tag